# Background service not starting android

Tags: android, notifications, background-service

I'm trying to use a background service so that I can check for new content on the app every 30 minutes and notify the user with a notification if there is any new content. The problem is that that service does not seem that it is starting at all. I'm not entirely sure what I have wrong.

I've followed this [article](http://it-ride.blogspot.it/2010/10/android-implementing-notification.html) to implement a notification service and this question as well -  [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android).

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.____.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.____.BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.____.NotificationService"/>
</application>
```

The **BootReceiver** should start the Service

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

The service **NotificationService** right now is set to display a simple notification

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    private WakeLock mWakeLock;

    /**
     * Simply return null, since our Service will not be communicating with
     * any other components. It just does its work silently.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * This is where we initialize. We call this when onStart/onStartCommand is
     * called by the system. We won't do anything with the intent here, and you
     * probably won't, either.
     */
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // obtain the wake lock
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My App");
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        // check the global background data setting
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {
            stopSelf();
            return;
        }

        // do the actual work, in a separate thread
        new PollTask().execute();
    }

    private class PollTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        /**
         * This is where YOU do YOUR work. There's nothing for me to write here
         * you have to fill this in. Make your HTTP request(s) or whatever it is
         * you have to do to get your updates in here, because this is run in a
         * separate thread
         */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // do stuff!

            // get last added date time of offer
            // every 60 minutes check for new offers

            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentText("New Content Available")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(0)
                .build();

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * In here you should interpret whatever you fetched in doInBackground
         * and push any notifications you need to the status bar, using the
         * NotificationManager. I will not cover this here, go check the docs on
         * NotificationManager.
         *
         * What you HAVE to do is call stopSelf() after you've pushed your
         * notification(s). This will:
         * 1) Kill the service so it doesn't waste precious resources
         * 2) Call onDestroy() which will release the wake lock, so the device
         *    can go to sleep again and save precious battery.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // handle your data
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is deprecated, but you have to implement it if you're planning on
     * supporting devices with an API level lower than 5 (Android 2.0).
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * This is called on 2.0+ (API level 5 or higher). Returning
     * START_NOT_STICKY tells the system to not restart the service if it is
     * killed because of poor resource (memory/cpu) conditions.
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handleIntent(intent);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    /**
     * In onDestroy() we release our wake lock. This ensures that whenever the
     * Service stops (killed for resources, stopSelf() called, etc.), the wake
     * lock will be released.
     */
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

Debugging the app with breakpoints in both **BootRecevier** and **NotificationService** are never triggered. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the way Background Services work.

**UPDATE**

I found this [article](http://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/2011/07/05/why-my-broadcastreceiver-does-not-get-called/) about why the BroadcastRecevier is not being called. One of the mentioned points is **PendingIntent requestCode missing**

I've updated the BootRecevier as follows to test out the service...called every 1 minute:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int minutes = 1;
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 54321, i, 0);
    am.cancel(pi);

    if (minutes > 0) {
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + minutes*60*1000,
            minutes*60*1000, pi);
    }
}
```

Changing 0 to a 'unique' `requestCode` 54321 somehow started triggering the service. The issue is that the service does not carry on working when the app is closed...not sure if that's a completely different thing altogether.

**UPDATE 2**

I've updated the `doInBackground` method in the **NotificationService**, using this [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/notifications/android-notifications-example/) to display notifications:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();

    // invoke default notification service
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);

    mBuilder.setContentTitle("[Notification Title]");
    mBuilder.setContentText("[Notification Text]");
    mBuilder.setTicker(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name));
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    return null;
}
```

I've tested it on an emulator and the Background Service works even when the app is closed. However, testing the app on an actual device did not display any notifications.

Comment: You can try starting service manually, if you want it to start it immediately. (I have a sticky message service when OS kills it, it takes some time to restart but if I need to start immediately I run this code)

context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the permission to receive the intent in your manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

You will only receive notifications of the device booting **after** the user has started your application at least once.

Comment: Yep that's already there...I'll update my question just in case

Comment: You have to declare the service **inside** of the `<application` tag. It's hard to guess your issues if you don't give the full code :-)

Answer (score -1):

I happened to have the same issue recently, and I am using a 5.1.1 android smartphone. The way I solved this issue was using the `ic_launcher in mipmap` to replace the `ic_launcher in drawable` when called setSmallIcon().

However, for the exact reason, I guess it has something to do with the difference between mipmap and drawable.

Ref: [mipmap vs drawable folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders)